# Put style.css below other css in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'am new in wordpress theme development. Now i have some problem with ordering some css.

My wordpress generate head tags like this

```
<head>
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/muarif/style.css">
   ...
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="normalize-css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/muarif/inc/css/normalize.css?ver=4.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
   <link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/muarif/inc/css/bootstrap.css?ver=4.1.1" type="text/css" media="all">
   ...
</head>
```

*edit for wp_enqueue_style

```
 function site_script(){
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/normalize.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/bootstrap.css');

    //jquery script
    wp_register_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    //angular script
    wp_register_script('angular',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/angular.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('angular');

    //bootstrap script
    wp_register_script('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','site_script');
```

Style.css is load automatically if it exist in theme. Now i want to put style.css below than other css and put normalize.css on top for overriding on each stylesheet. I use wp_enqueue_style and fill $deps parameter. But it dont make anything happen.

Any advice?

Comment: Can you share your wp_enqueue_style code? Looks like you can fix that by simply moving them around, rather than setting parameters.

Comment: I don't think style.css is automatically enqueued by WordPress. There must be some other function (or template file) that's loading the stylesheet. You might look in your theme's header.php to see if it's hard coded in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this code instead of yours in the question. Also search and remove any other `wp_enqueue_style`, I think the default one is being loading somewhere else before. Also check if it's hardcoded in `header.php`

```
function site_script(){
    wp_enqueue_style('normalize',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/normalize.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/css/bootstrap.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('theme_name',get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');

    //jquery script
    wp_register_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    //angular script
    wp_register_script('angular',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/angular.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('angular');

    //bootstrap script
    wp_register_script('bootstrap',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js',array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','site_script');
```

You might also need to update the jQuery part like this:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery',get_template_directory_uri().'/inc/js/jquery.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

FYI: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Comment: if i re-declare style.css, it should be double css loaded.

Comment: that style.css must be previously loaded before, see updated answer.